# How to connect to SQL Server Database from ios application?

Tags: ios, xcode

I am new to the iOS development world so please bear with me.

I have a web application which has a SQL Server 2008 database. I am planning to develop an iPad application which will basically be a tablet version of the web application and the main requirement is to access the same SQL Server Datbase  to access the data.  I am not sure how to begin with this. Are there any SQL Server connection libraries similar to ADO.NET for xcode?

Comment: Check this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4691420/query-sql-server-database-from-native-ios-application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can move the database to Microsoft Azure SQL database and use the iOS mobile toolkit provided by Microsoft connect to it.

Comment: that is really nice, i did not know azure sql database supported that but its great to know. I might just go this route

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no way to do this.
I think you should create an API to work with database, and use it to manipulate data.

Comment: I see, I could possibly create web services and then have the ipad make requests to the web service.