# Can I run PHP Scripts on iOS device?

Tags: php, ios, sql-server, nsurlconnection

I have an application that gets data from a SQL Server database using a PHP Script stored in an online server.

I get the data on my iOS app with **NSURLConnection**, I connect to the script and the script executes the queries on the server.

My question is, can I store this script on the iPhone or iPad and forget the online server?
Also, can I execute SQL Server queries without PHP Scripts and POST methods?

Comment: There probably isn't a PHP interpreter for iOS, no.  Even if there was, you'd have to be able to connect to the database.  Which leads to your second question... You technically *can* open your database directly to the internet and skip having server-side code, but it's *very* ill-advised to do so.  Anybody else would be able to send requests to your database too.

Comment: How would putting the PHP file on the iOS device eliminate the need for the online server? You still need access to the SQL Server database which is on the server.

Comment: No. You can't. You can make http requests from ios to a webserver, and that webserver runs the php for you.

Comment: You don't want to attempt to access a DB directly from your iOS code.  Any intrepid hacker could easily get at your DB credentials stored in the application and access your DB, especially since you would need to open up your DB to calls from any arbitrary remote IP address to make this work.  A very bad idea.  Stick with keeping your DB behind a service layer.

Comment: refer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4691420/query-sql-server-database-from-native-ios-application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was searching a lot of time for some library to do that I want. I found this library:

https://github.com/martinrybak/SQLClient

Main blog of the proyect:

http://objcsharp.wordpress.com/2013/10/15/an-open-source-sql-server-library-for-ios/

If you know another Libraries you can post in this thread for help the people with the same problem.

Regards.

Answer (score 2):

If your database is static(no update), then you can use iOS's native CoreData to manage the database locally and you dont need internet connection at all.

If your database needs to be updated after you release your application, then you will need a server.

In either case the programming language on iOS will be Objective C and C++ (instead of Python).